# Haskell case statement grammar

Tags: haskell

How to understand the `case args of` in the following code?

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  case args of
    [dir, mbytes] | [(bytes ,"")] <- reads mbytes
                   , bytes >= 1 -> findDuplicates dir bytes
    (_) -> do
      name <- getProgName
      printf "Something went wrong - please use ./%s <dir> <bytes>\n" name
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I think it's a pretty reasonable question: "what the heck is going on with this `case` expression which clearly does not conform to standard Haskell?" If you know about `PatternGuards` then of course the answer is obvious, but if you don't know about it what more can you ask than "huh?"

Comment: This may be more useful to people searching for what this syntax means if you edit the question title to something more descriptive like “What does a left arrow mean in a guard?”

Comment: @JonPurdy You have the power to make that edit yourself, if you think it would be an improvement (and I think most folks would agree with you that it would be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guards in this `case` expression are making use of the [`PatternGuards`](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/pattern-and-guard-extensions#patternguards) extension, part of Haskell 2010 but not Haskell 98. The idea is that with this extension, your guards can do pattern-matching of their own, not just evaluate `Bool` expressions.

So your `case` expression has two patterns:

```
[dir, mbytes]
```

and the wildcard pattern. If `[dir, mbytes]` does match with args, the pattern match still might not succeed: its guards need to apply. It has two guards:

```
[(bytes ,"")] <- reads mbytes
```

which means that calling `reads mbytes` must match with `[(bytes, "")]`, and

```
bytes >= 1
```

which is an ordinary boolean expression.

If all of those pattern matches and guards succeed, then the first clause of the `case` is the one that is used; otherwise, we fall through to the default clause and print an error message.